# Eliminar en SQL DB2 registro de hace un año

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, db2

Desde mi aplicación en Java voy a controlar una sentencia SQL que consiste en eliminar los registros de una tabla de hace un año. La sentencia sería algo así:

```
DELETE FROM TABLA WHERE FECHA >= 1 año.
```

La columna FECHA de esa tabla es un char de 8 caracteres y estaría escrito de forma *"YYYYMMDD"*

¿Podrías echarme una mano para ver crear esa sentencia?

Muchas gracias

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar las funciones date_add() y otras con las que poder manipular y comparar fechas necesitarás pasar ese campo FECHA a un tipo Date. A continuación te propongo un fragmento para poder hacerlo y así comparar al gusto:

```sql
SELECT DATE(CONCAT_WS("-",SUBSTRING(Fecha, 1, 4), SUBSTRING(Fecha, 5, 2), SUBSTRING(Fecha, 7, 2)));
```

Comment: Gracias, entiendo que ese fragmento sirve tanto para la parte SELECT como la parte WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero utilizar YEARS_BETWEEN para calcular los años y CURRENT DATE para obtener el día de hoy y comparar con la fecha del campo. El campo se convierte a fecha armando un string de tipo YYYY-MM-DD y aplicándole DATE()

Así quedaría tu query modificado:

```
DELETE FROM TABLA WHERE YEARS_BETWEEN(CURRENT DATE, DATE(SUBSTR(FECHA,1,4)||SUBSTR(FECHA,5,2)||SUBSTR(FECHA,7,2))) >= 1
```